# capture audio and visualize it android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Hi I am using canvas to draw captured audio records I have this code but some how it gives me the fft of the audio signal I don't get which part of the code does that ?? and what should I do to make it draw the waveform it self not the fft ??

```
public void doDraw(Canvas paramCanvas)
{
  if (mCanvasHeight == 1)
    mCanvasHeight = paramCanvas.getHeight();
  paramCanvas.drawPaint(mBackPaint); 
  /**
   * Set some base values as a starting point
   * This could be considerd as a part of the calculation process
   */
  int height = paramCanvas.getHeight();
  int BuffIndex = (mBuffer.length / 2 - paramCanvas.getWidth()) / 2;
  int width = paramCanvas.getWidth();
  int mBuffIndex = BuffIndex;
  int scale = height / m_iScaler;
  int StratX = 0;
  if (StratX >= width)
  {
    paramCanvas.save();
    return;
  }
int cu1 = 0;
/**
 * Here is where the real calculations is taken in to action
 * In this while loop, we calculate the start and stop points
 * for both X and Y
 * 
 * The line is then drawer to the canvas with drawLine method
 */
while (StratX < width -1)
{
  int StartBaseY = mBuffer[(mBuffIndex - 1)] / scale;

  int StopBaseY = mBuffer[mBuffIndex] / scale;
  if (StartBaseY > height / 2)
  {
      StartBaseY = 1 + height / 2;
    int checkSize = height / 2;
    if (StopBaseY <= checkSize)
        return;
    StopBaseY = 2 + height / 2;
  }

    int StartY = StartBaseY + height / 2;
    int StopY = StopBaseY + height / 2;
    paramCanvas.drawLine(StratX, StartY, StratX +1, StopY, mLinePaint);
    cu1++;
    mBuffIndex++;
    StratX++;
    int checkSize_again = -1 * (height / 2);
    if (StopBaseY >= checkSize_again)
      continue;
    StopBaseY = -2 + -1 * (height / 2);
  }
}
```

So basically main activity calls three functions in the CSampler class

```
init() //which prepares the audio record and sets its configuration
Start recording() // starts the audio recorder
StartSampling() // reads data into CSampler.buffer;
```

---

StartSampling function called

```
public void StartSampling()
{
recordingThread = new Thread()
{
  public void run()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      if (!m_bRun.booleanValue())
      {
        m_bDead = Boolean.valueOf(true);
        m_bDead2 = Boolean.valueOf(true);
        return;
      }
      Sample();

      m_ma.setBuffer(CSampler.buffer); //m_ma is object of main activity 
    }
   }
 };
 recordingThread.start();
```

}

---

Function setBuffer in main activity

```
/** 
 * Recives the buffer from the sampler
 * @param buffert
 */
public void setBuffer(short[] paramArrayOfShort)
{
  mDrawThread = mdrawer.getThread();
  mDrawThread.setBuffer(paramArrayOfShort);
}
```

Which basically calls another function in the CDrawer class

Function SetBuffer in CDrawer class sets the mbuffer with the same read data =/

```
public void setBuffer(short[] paramArrayOfShort)
{
  synchronized (mBuffer)
  {
    mBuffer = paramArrayOfShort;
    return;
  }
}
```

---

```
public void Sample()
{
mSamplesRead = ar.read(buffer, 0, buffersizebytes);
}
___________________________________________________
```

[image: output pic]

---

[image]

Comment: This piece of code doesn't help much. mBuffer contains the fft result. Replace this with the raw signal data and do the appropriate x- and y-scaling.

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger thanks for the quick reply but that's the issue I don't get where in the code the programming does change the recorded data into fft.. it's not very obvious to me .. I got the code from this resource:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/303235-visualizing-sound-from-the-microphone/

Comment: Just simply search your complete code for writing access to `mBuffer` and post that piece of code instead

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger I have added the all the functions that call each other to eventually set the mbuffer

Comment: OK, I had a look at the code you pointed to .. it is really terrible to start with. Actually, I am quite sure it doesn't even work. There is no call to an FFT, so how should it be able to show a spectrum?!

Comment: In `StartSampling()` is a call to `Sample()`. Where is the source of that?

Comment: public void Sample()
  {
    mSamplesRead = ar.read(buffer, 0, buffersizebytes);
    
  }

Comment: Ok, the fog begins to lift. You're assuming that this app shows an FFT of the audio signal, but actually it does not. I think I am ready for a real answer. Shall I?

Comment: yes please enlighten me >> yes because the one who developed the app claim that the output is an fft of the input but running the code I got confused because it seems to me that it is neither the audio signal nor its fft :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the display shows a very short piece of the audio signal waveform. To be more precise, each screen pixel vertical line shows one sample value of the signal. As the signal is sampled with 44.1kHz there are 44100 sample values per second. If your screen has a physical pixel width of say 768 pixels, then you see 768/44100 = 0.017s = 17ms of the signal.

This is rather short: with a typical male voice you will see about two cycles of the fundamental frequency.

With a quick change in the source you can see a little bit more of the signal waveform: Just change `SAMPPERSEC = 44100` to e.g. `SAMPPERSEC = 16000`;

The code does not contain any call to a Fourier transformation or any other spectral transformation, so it is simply not able to show a spectrum.

Comment: Alright yes I got u but how can I increase that duration or the part of signal displayed >> my goal is to display 2 seconds of the signal do I have to change the width of the canvas to do that ?

Comment: Ok, this is a follow-up question. If you agree with my answer I would be happy if you mark it as such. To display 2 seconds you have two possibilities: 1) you rewrite the `while` loop in `onDraw` (it is terrible code), and 2) (a simple but awful work-around) put the `StratX++;` inside of an `if` and use a counter to execute it only once in e.g. 100 times. This causes the `while` loop to run 100 times longer and ploting the lines over and over at the same screen pixels, but it will do what you want.

Comment: I don't really quite get what you mean ^^" I guess I need to learn more about how the canvas works before :S

Comment: During the `while` loop the signal curve is drawn segment-wise from left to right. `StratX` is the x-position of the actual segment. Now, each sample value is assigned to each screen vertical pixel line. If you prefer to see more signal on the canvas you have to assign more samples to one pixel line. My 2nd suggestion was the simplest way to do that. But a complete rewrite is a good starting point to learn!

Comment: Okay the only change that actually did on my app was minimizing the width of screen where my signal updates> check the pic above please

Comment: ok! Anyway, you need to carefully think about how to draw more samples than screen pixels and then re-write the drawing loop. We should stop this discussion here as it is too close to a chat.